# Slow Phone USB 3.0 Speeds on Windows 7, but not Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, android, speed

Phone: Pixel XL

Cable Used: anker powerline+ ([https://www.amazon.com/Anker-Powerli.../dp/B01GN0M6NE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GN0M6NE))

When copying the same file from my labtop using linux i can copy in about 2mins (3gb movie)
On Windows 7 that file will take more than 5 mins usually 8 (windows dialog box says 12)

Ive reinstalled intel usb3 drivers, set my xhci to smart auto, handoff enabled

Android drivers as well as adb are installed

Using USB Device Tree Viewer i can see that it is connected to a usb 3.0 HUB and:
Device Bus Speed : 0x03 (SuperSpeed)

Meaning it should have usb 3.0 speeds.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Could be the AV reading the file while it's transferring slowing it down? Have you tried to stop scanning of AV on USB ports?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Arch(Antergos)

Comment: @Karasu-O-Matic ill give that a try however if the file is on my hard drive and im transferring that to another drive(phone) I don't think it would have an issue. But to make note as far as AV im using Avast/Malwarebytes

Comment: According to this http://piunikaweb.com/2017/09/26/pixel-users-reporting-issues-with-usb-file-transfers-post-oreo-update/ it could also be a bug from Oreo. Is that the version of Android you're running?

Comment: @Karasu-O-Matic Im using Nougat 7.1.2 (Rooted)

Comment: Disabled all AV, no difference whatsoever

Comment: Can you use a different distro of Linux on your system

Comment: Could you check on a different Windows machine and replicate the issue? If you try different phones is the speed transfer normal?